# Adding a grey border to the edge of my website using CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to add a border to the edges of my website like [this](http://dovetail-demo.squarespace.com/?invitationId=FA6ELD5LWP2RDJHH7YM9): ( I'm referring to the grey border on the left and right edges of the site)

[image]

I'm struggling to complete this with CSS. The one thing I don't understand is how the shadowing is created between the white and the grey.
Can someone help?

Comment: Use Firebug for Fx or developer tools in Chrome/Opera/IE, and you can easily see this stuff for yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Try `box-shadow` on the container element:

```
.container {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #666;
}
```

Adjust the size (10px), blur (10px) and color (#666) as needed.

Answer (score 2):

That is done with a simple `box-shadow`. Demo: http://jsbin.com/ivugeh/1/edit

```
<body>

  <div class="page">

  </div>

</body>
```

```
body { 
  background: url('http://dovetail-demo.squarespace.com/assets/concrete-texture.png'); 
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0;
}
.page {
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  background: #fff;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please always make sure to include relevant code directly in your post.